# Hadoop Custom Key or Custome Writable Comparable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

**Example 1 :** [here is an implementation of custom writable](http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2012/05/hadoop-recipe-implementing-custom-writable/)
Q1 But what if we want to make it a custom writableComparable, ?
Ans: We need to implement compareTo() method, also a rowComparator to make it work fast.

**Example 2 :** [Text Pair Example page 104-107](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=drbI_aro20oC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=hadoop+custom+writable+example&source=bl&ots=tZDlvifZe8&sig=tu1uraZgYgL97eakcobdIGbMoxE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AzYcUu7uC4HtrQedvIBw&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=TextPair&f=false)

**Q2,** What if I have more than 2 text fields, one long writeable field in my custom object ?
As in **Example 1**, the code snippet of Comparator.Compare method.
This would work with the data type contains only **two attribute which are  Text**.

What if, the custom data type is **having more than two elements, and that too, one Text, Two IntWaritable, one BooleanAritable**

How to Implement a rawComparator in such case ?

```
public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, 
           byte[] b2, int s2, int l2)   {
  try {
     int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
     int firstL2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2);
     int cmp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);
     if (cmp != 0) {
         return cmp;
      }
  return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1 + firstL1,
            l1 - firstL1,b2, s2 + firstL2, l2 - firstL2);
  }catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? Where you have the problem? Can you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: What I require is an implementation of a custom writable, with taw comparator, just like TextPair as in example 1, which contains more than two Text Object & one LongWritable object,

The important stuff is an implementation of RawComparator for CustomWritable which has at least 3 Text Object and a LongWritable object.

Comment: the thing is if you have more that two Custom Objects which have three Text object as fields, say you have the text for each seperated by '\t' something like "text1" + "\t" + "text2 + "\t" + "text2", you can compare the two Custom Objects using RawComparator like `int compare(byte[] bytesCustomObject1, int s1, int l1,
                       byte[] bytesCustomObject2, int s2, int l2)`. Is this the case you are trying to deal with?

Comment: NOT AT ALL, I am talking about Text Objects & LongWritable Objects as attributes to a (has a relation with a) WritableComparable class.
  see Text Pair Class, 
`Class TextPair{`
`private Text first; `
`private Text second;`
`}`

or `public class RequestInfo implements Writable {` in Example one

Comment: Comparing text and long all depends on the usecase requirement. Suppose I have a person class with 2 text fields name & gender and one int field age. If I have a requirement to compare person1 and person2, it is upto me to deside how to compare both. I would say age1 compareto age2 and on both being equal I would go for an alphabet comparison on name and in case both are still equal I would go for a gender comparison on both,In worst case if all are equal, simply it says person1 = person2. I am doubtful if I fully understand the question.

Comment: @user2458922: I don't think TextPair is comparing first to second belonging to the same TextPair object, rather comparing two TextPairs.

Comment: TextPair compares this.first with that.first, if they are equeal, then compares this.second with that.second,
@ArunAK , The rawComparator does the same, withOut de-serialising the data into objects,
My question is about How to implement a raw comparator when we have more than 2 Text and one Non Text fields

Comment: @user2458922, then where is the problem, binary compare TP1(1st+2nd+3rd fields) with TP1(1st+2nd+3rd fields) and TP1(Non-Text field) with TP2(Non-Text field)?  To directly compare the Non-Text fields, you need to do some offset calculation.

Comment: @JtheRocker This Offset Calculation is the challenge, 
to compare this.Second with other.second,
` int cmp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);`
`        if (cmp != 0) {`
 `         return cmp;`
`        }`
`        return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1 + firstL1, l1 - firstL1,`
 `                                      b2, s2 + firstL2, l2 - `firstL2);
      } '

What Must be 
`TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1 + firstL1, l1 - firstL1,
                                       b2, s2 + firstL2, l2 - firstL2);`
      }' 
**When we have more than two TEXT and a LongWritable ?**

Comment: Any Body .. Answer Please

Comment: Instead of TEXTPAIR class, which has two attributes , which are of the same type, Text 
I would like to introduce a StudentCalss,
Which has 3 Attribute,

'class StudentCalss extends writable comparator
{Text name,
Longwritable regNumber}'

How to have a row comparator which would compare Name and then regNumber ? @SSaikia_JtheRocker